# I cannot execute my bootloader file in qemu emulator

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bootloader

```
org 0x7c00 

section .text
    mov ah, 0x0e  
    mov si, message  

print_loop:
    lodsb            
    or al, al        
    jz done          
    int 0x10        
    jmp print_loop   

done:
    hlt             

section .data
    message db "Hello, World!", 0 

times 510-($-$$) db 0   
dw 0xaa55
```

When I try to execute this code in my qemu emulator, it shows "no bootable device found". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the actual *content* of the generated boot sector to make sure it complies with the rules. I think that's basically just ensuring the final two bytes are the correct signature.

The reason I bring this up is because I think `$-$$` is the *wrong* thing to use here, if you're using sections. It works out the difference between current location and the start of the *section,* not the start of the boot sector.

So, with a code section of fifteen bytes and an immediately following data section of fourteen bytes (both roughly what you have), `510 - ($ - $$)` in the data section becomes `510 - (29 - 15) = 496`. That means you will have:

- 15 bytes of code.
- 14 bytes of data.
- 496 bytes of padding.

That's a total of `525` bytes before you generate the signature so it *won't* be at the correct location, meaning the boot loader will not recognise the disk as bootable. In this case, offset `1fe` will contain two of the `00` bytes from the padding.

The following listing generated by your original code confirms this:

```
                         org 0x7c00
                         section .text
00000000 B40E                mov ah, 0x0e
00000002 BE[0000]            mov si, message
                         print_loop:
00000005 AC                  lodsb
00000006 08C0                or al, al
00000008 7404                jz done
0000000A CD10                int 0x10
0000000C EBF7                jmp print_loop
                         done:
0000000E F4                  hlt
                         section .data
00000000                 message:
00000000 48656C6C6F2C20      db "Hello, World!", 0
00000008 576F726C642100
0000000E 00<*496>            times 510-($-$$) db 0
000001FE 55AA                dw 0xaa55
```

You can see that the signature is at offset `1fe` but that offset is relative to the start of the *data section* (because the message is at offset `000` within that section). That means it's not taking into account how much space is used by the code when combining the two sections into a boot sector.

---

If instead you place it all in *one* section, the expression should then become `510 - (29 - 0) = 481`, giving the correct `510` bytes before the signature:

- 15 bytes of code.
- 14 bytes of data.
- 481 bytes of padding.

This still looks like the signature goes at offset `1fe` in the listing but that's the offset within the code (and only) section, with the message at `00f`. There's also less padding between the message and the signature:

```
                         org 0x7c00
                         section .text
00000000 B40E                mov ah, 0x0e
00000002 BE[0000]            mov si, message
                         print_loop:
00000005 AC                  lodsb
00000006 08C0                or al, al
00000008 7404                jz done
0000000A CD10                int 0x10
0000000C EBF7                jmp print_loop
                         done:
0000000E F4                  hlt
0000000F                 message:
0000000F 48656C6C6F2C20      db "Hello, World!", 0
00000016 576F726C642100
0000001D 00<*481>            times 510-($-$$) db 0
000001FE 55AA                dw 0xaa55
```

---

And just some minor points on your code.

First, `hlt` will indeed halt the CPU but the next external interrupt can restart it. Since you probably don't want that to try and execute your message, it may be worthwhile protecting against that with:

```
done:
    hlt
    jmp done
```

Second, when BIOS transfers control to your code, there's very little that you should rely on. For example, you should *not* assume that `ds` is set to, as you seem to expect it, the same value as `cs`.

You should *explicitly* force that to be the case, as well as setting up anything else that's needed such as the stack pointer.

Comment: Assuming `ds` = 0 is not the same as assuming `ds` = `cs` because `cs` can also be nonzero. Also, in the very next instruction after the one that changes `ss` you should also change `sp`. Furthermore, using two sections is possible with a padding line like `times 510 - ($ - $$) - (text_end - text_start) db 0` if the proper labels are placed in the `.text` section and alignment is taken care of. (Either specify `align=1` as a section attribute, or place an appropriate `align` directive before the label `text_end`.)

Comment: @ecm, you can't really assume either of those things, it depends on what the BIOS did before calling you. That's a good point on the sp register, I've modified the text to include it as well, removing the code to avoid other possibilities like needing `cli`, etc.. And you may be right on how sections *could* work but , for something this simple, I'd just avoid them. They don't really give you anything useful in this scenario. They're nice for programs with lots of parts so those parts can be combined nicely but, given you have only 500-odd bytes, that's not likely.

Comment: This means that `section .data` should be outside `section .text`, not inside ? Because `$$`  should be calculated from begining of `section .text` ?

Comment: @0Signal: you need to include both code and data when calculating the value to subtract from 510 (in order to pad). That means, regardless of whether order is code/data or data/code, the value you must subtract from `$` in the second is the `$$` from the *first.* That's why I state it's easier just to use one segment.

Comment: Well, my `.map` file says `.text` starts `7c00` length `0x0200` bytes and `.data` starts `7e00` length `0x000e`. Qemu monitor dump shows that `.text` is in right place but `.data` is random values, should be `message` and instruction `mov si, message` is `BE 00 7E`. `[7E00] = 0` so nothing is printed on the screen.

Comment: @0Signal, I would suggest that whatever you're using to combine those sections is not working. The whole lot needs to fit within 510 bytes so with code at 7c00 and data at 7e00, that's 512 bytes apart so impossible to fit.